# Convert to UTF-8-BOM memory optimiztion

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

Is there a better way to write this code section in Python with an emphasis on memory usage?
convert csv from UTF-8 to UTF-8-BOM ( work better with Hebrew )

```py
def convert_csv_to_utf8_bom(input_file_path, output_file_path, logger: Logger):
    """
    Convert a CSV file format to UTF 8 Bom 
    """
    logger.debug(f"convert csv to utf8 bom")
    with open(input_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        content = f.read()
    with open(output_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Comment: Why do you want this in the first place? The most common reason is to load CSV files in Excel **by double-clicking**, in which case a *better* solution could be to create real Excel files with `openpyxl` or `pandas.to_excel` directly. Excel can load UTF8 files without problem if you go to the `Data > Insert` menu.

Comment: Also adding a BOM really shouldn't matter in any application that has normal Unicode support for years now, what are you trying to load this _in_?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Microsoft is the worst offender for not defaulting to UTF-8 without a BOM.  I'm guessing Excel is the culprit.

Comment: I'd prefer not to guess, though =D (mostly because depending on the application, and the version of that application, this work might not be necessary)

Answer (score 4):

All you want to do is add a few bytes to the beginning of the file. Note there's no need to decode and re-encode the entire file to do that. I would write the appropriate BOM taken from the `codecs` module first, then copy the input file to your output file using `shutil.copyfileobj`.

```
import codecs
from shutil import copyfileobj

def convert_csv_to_utf8_bom(input_file_path, output_file_path, logger: Logger):
   
    logger.debug(f"convert csv to utf8 bom")
    with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as out, open(input_file_path, 'rb') as in_:
        out.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
        copyfileobj(in_, out)
```

`copyfileobj` takes an optional 3rd argument to control buffering. When enabled (by default), it alternates between reading fixed-size chunks of data from the input and writing it to the output.

1. A negative integer tells `copyobjfile` to read the entire file
   as one big chunk.
2. `0` (the default) uses an OS-specific buffer size (64 KB for Windows, 1 MB otherwise.)
3. A positive integer specifies the size of the buffer explicitly.

Comment: Why do you suppose the default buffer is so much smaller for Windows?

Comment: No idea; I just pulled those from the source.

Comment: I was really curious to see how your solution works and performs, but I get an error when I run it, `AttributeError: 'itertools.chain' object has no attribute 'read'`, which I've tested and documented in my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78063347/246801).

Comment: Bah, my fault. I forgot `copyfileobj` actually wants a file-like object. `chain` was a late substitution for my original solution, which was to call `out.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)` before `copyfileobj(in_, out)`. I'll fix.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to read the full input, you can read line by line if that helps:

```py
def convert_csv_to_utf8_bom(input_file_path, output_file_path, logger: Logger):
    """
    Convert a CSV file format to UTF 8 Bom 
    """
    logger.debug(f"convert csv to utf8 bom")
    with open(input_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as f_in:
        with open(output_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline="") as f_out:
            for row in f_in:
                f_out.write(row)
```

Comment: No need to use two `with` statements, you can combine them: `with open(input_file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f_in,
open(output_file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline="") as f_out:`

Comment: I think you need to add `newline=''` to the reader, otherwise it'll munge newlines and result in a less-than-perfect copy. I've tested and documented this in my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78063347/246801).

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to compare solutions from [JonSG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78062305/246801) and [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78062387/246801) to see if any ran particularly faster (particularly to see if chepner's ran faster), and to see if they only add the BOM (and don't mutate the text along the way).

They both only add a BOM, and chepner's looks to be about 10x faster.

My comparator:

1. runs and times both functions against a 10MB UTF-8 encoded file of random text that runs the full spectrum of Unicode, minus invalid UTF-16 surrogate pairs
2. reads the output and asserts the output has a BOM; also chomps the BOM leaving what should be the original UTF-8 bytes
3. prints results

```py
def compare():
    import time

    for name_out, func in [
        ("output-stream.txt", convert_stream),  # JonSG
        ("output-copy.txt", convert_copy),      # chepner
    ]:
        beg = time.monotonic()
        func(FNAME_TXT, name_out)
        delta = time.monotonic() - beg

        with open(FNAME_TXT, "rb") as f:
            input_sans_bom = f.read()

        with open(name_out, "rb") as f:
            first_three = f.read(3)
            assert first_three == b"\xEF\xBB\xBF", f"first three bytes of '{FNAME_TXT}'={first_three}; want BOM (b'\\xEF\\xBB\\xBF')"  # fmt: skip
            output_sans_bom = f.read()

        print(
            f"{func.__name__} ran in {delta:.4f} s; output==input = {output_sans_bom==input_sans_bom}"
        )
```

The results (without the the redundant BOM check msg):

```
generated random txt w/size  1048578
  convert_stream ran in 0.0034 s
  convert_copy   ran in 0.0011 s

generated random txt w/size 10485752
  convert_stream ran in 0.0228 s
  convert_copy   ran in 0.0028 s

generated random txt w/size 52428753
  convert_stream ran in 0.1113 s
  convert_copy   ran in 0.0136 s
```

The complete script that generates and runs the comparison can be found in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/zacharysyoung/717961ba5f325170faedf9aaf94cdd88#file-main-py).

To follow-up on OP's comment asking about memory...

JonSG's streaming solution reads one line into memory, immediately writes it out, and moves on to the next line; so it never needs more memory than the single biggest line in the file.

On my system the Python run takes about 5MB:

```
% /usr/bin/time -l python3 -c 'print("foo")'
foo
        0.03 real         0.02 user         0.00 sys
        ...
        5_358_848  peak memory footprint
```

So for the memory footprints that follow, subtract ~5MB to calculate the memory cost of copying the data between the input and output files.

chepner's solution offers some flexibility in that you can specify how big a block you want to copy.  Running that with a block size of 64K, I got these memory footprints when copying a 100K, 1MB, and 10MB file:

```
100_KB.txt
        0.03 real         0.02 user         0.00 sys
        7_160_896  peak memory footprint
  1_MB.txt
        0.02 real         0.01 user         0.00 sys
        7_177_280  peak memory footprint
 10_MB.txt
        0.02 real         0.01 user         0.00 sys
        7_193_728  peak memory footprint
```

~2MB to do the actual copies.  Bumping the block size up to 1MB: copying the 1MB file used ~8MB of memory; copying the 10MB file used ~11MB of memory.

If you have sufficiently large files and a sufficient amount of memory, you might get faster copies by specifying bigger block sizes (which will reduce the number of sys calls Python has to make to read a block and then write it).

Comment: tnx for the comparison
can you do the same for memory consumption or share your opinion on what is better?

Comment: @idanovadia, you're welcome. Answered the question about memory above. Good luck!